# kernel panic: unable to mount root in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel, mount, hard-drive, root

I just booted up my ubuntu partition, it was working and I've installed the updates via the software updater but it crashed at the end, so I've restarted the pc and now I'm getting this:

[image]

I guess it's a kernel panic related to the hard drive. How can I fix this, I need to copy my SSH keys at least.

PS: I have windows 7 also installed on a different partition and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is to perform a file system check on your Ubuntu disk...

- boot to the GRUB menu (where you select which OS to start)
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors

If you can't do the above, then....

- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD
- start `gparted` and determine which is your Ubuntu partition
- open `terminal` and type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` changing the X to the appropriate number of your Ubuntu partition
- repeat the `fsck` if there are errors

Now we use the SMART internal disk monitoring tools to see if it detects a pending hard disk failure...

- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD
- start the `Disks` application from the Unity dash
- select the hard disk in the left pane
- click on the "hamburger" icon in the top-right of the Disks window
- select `SMART Data & Tests`
- view the data, and run the tests

Then try to recover from the failed installs *(this only applies if you're coming from step #1)*...

- type `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` # to remount root as read/write
- type `sudo dpkg --configure -a` # to fix broken dpkg
- type `sudo apt-get install -f` # to finish upgrades
- type `reboot`

Comment: It's only been an hour! ;)

Comment: @NonnyMoose somebody has to teach the newbies how it all works here :-)

Comment: LOL I would have waited at least a day. ;) XD

Comment: @NonnyMoose no, 'cause newbies usually don't come back after they get an answer, or sometimes just not at all :-)

Comment: Dont worry i'll give you feedback once i get home and try this, even tho i already tried the recovery mode and i remeber getting the same error as in the picture.

Comment: @Getsuga if my answer doesn't work as is, we'll try similar repairs when booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD. Just let me know. Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema yes i'm willing to try this via live ubuntu thx for the tip 

Comment: @Getsuga see my updated procedure

Comment: I select the  Recovery mode, but the same errors happened in the recovery mode